# IF statement inside a loop in linux terminal not working

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, for-loop

Currently I am trying to execute a bash file in a crontab. However, the command by itself is not working, this is the command.

```
for ip in $(seq 3 80); do for ip2 in $(seq 9 254); do count=$(ping -c 1 192.168.$ip.$ip2 | grep icmp* | wc -l) if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then echo "Host unreachable" else php /var/www/phpfile.php 192.168.$ip.$ip2 > 192.168.$ip.$ip2.txt; done; done
```

The error that the console is showing when I execute this command is this:

```
if: Command not found
```

I already checked the spaces between the brackets, I also tried to remove them, but none of those solutions have worked. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my command? What am I missing?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You're missing some line breaks (recommended) or semicolons between your statements. Put the script into a separate file, formatted so that it is readable and call it from your crontab.

Comment: You're also missing a `fi` closing the `if` ... `else`

Comment: A prime example why long lines (and horizontal scrollbars) suck. If this were several lines, the error would be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `fi` and some `;`, Try this:

```
for ip in $(seq 3 80); do for ip2 in $(seq 9 254); do count=$(ping -c 1 192.168.$ip.$ip2 | grep icmp* | wc -l); if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then echo "Host unreachable"; else php /var/www/phpfile.php 192.168.$ip.$ip2 > 192.168.$ip.$ip2.txt;fi; done; done
```

It's better (for readability) to break codes into multiple lines insead of putting them all in a single line:

```
for ip in $(seq 3 80); do
 for ip2 in $(seq 9 254); do 
  count=$(ping -c 1 192.168.$ip.$ip2 | grep icmp* | wc -l)
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then 
   echo "Host unreachable"
   else php /var/www/phpfile.php 192.168.$ip.$ip2 > 192.168.$ip.$ip2.txt;
  fi
 done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your "one-line" script is totally unreadable, so it's no surprise that it contains errors. Change it to this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for ip in $(seq 3 80); do 
    for ip2 in $(seq 9 254); do 
        dest="192.168.$ip.$ip2"
        if ping -c 1 "$dest" | grep -q 'icmp*'; then 
            php /var/www/phpfile.php "$dest" > "$dest".txt
        else 
            echo "Host unreachable"                
        fi
    done
done
```

and call it from your crontab.

I have removed the useless use of `grep | wc -l`, in place of using `grep -q`, which returns success if the pattern is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Just since no one else seemed to comment on this.

The reason you got `if: Command not found` as an error is that the body of your inner loop:

```
count=$(ping -c 1 192.168.$ip.$ip2 | grep icmp* | wc -l) if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then echo "Host unreachable" else php /var/www/phpfile.php 192.168.$ip.$ip2 > 192.168.$ip.$ip2.txt
```

was being seen by the shell as a single command and not two commands.

Specifically it was being see as (cleaned up to make it more obvious):

```
count=$(command) if arg1 arg2 arg3 > outfile
```

Which then made `if` the command name (and `count` a variable set in the environment for that `if` command) and not, as you expected, a shell keyword akin to how this works:

```
$ printenv | grep FOO
$ FOO=bar printenv | grep FOO
FOO=bar
```